# Create a migration for the model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There is a model:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Категория")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

There is a DB context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

How do I create a migration based on a model class? The `Add-Migration Category` command creates only an empty migration.

Comment: Have you checked your connection string properly please?

Comment: DB connection OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework command 'dotnet ef migrations add nameofmigration' will generate a migration with all the changes made to your DbSet models you defined on your context , if a previous migration already added all your changes then yes it will create an empty migration